# Benefits of man makers workout

Tags: workout, strength-training

What are the benefits of the [Man Makers workout](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/man-maker)? Which muscles will it develop? How many sets and reps everyday do I need to do for muscle growth?

Comment: it seems like you need to read at the source. Have you googled this exercise?

Comment: Currently this is unclear, what is a "man maker" workout?

Comment: Welcome to PhysicalFitness.SE! Your question as it stands is too vague and needs to be revised in order to get a detailed response. Is this a particular exercise, or is this a full workout that contains multiple exercises, can you explain in detail on either case?

Comment: Man Maker  workout is particular exercise! More details on this site: [bodybuilding.com/exercises/man-maker](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/man-maker)

Comment: I want know which part of muscles in body will grow doing man maker? I thought one of the muscles which grow via man maker workout is lower back ! Maybe another muscles grow via man maker workout?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the benefits of man makers workout?

You have all the benefits. Improving your health, performance and increase your self esteem, etc. when you start seeing the results you will not want to stop and this will motivated you in your workouts.

> Which part of my muscle will grow?

It depends on your purpose. For beginners, I recommend the compound exercises (bench press, deadlift & squat). These exercises work the body completely and help you to gain a
good structure.

> How many sets and reps everyday do I need to do for muscle growing?

The most important is to "shock" the muscle. For each exercise, start with 3-4 sets with 10-15 reps then you will adjust as soon as you gain experience and know your body. You can divide your workout into:

- **push day:**

  chest, front and side delts, triceps
- **pull day:**

  back, back delts, biceps
- **leg day:**

  quads, hamstrings, calfs

For some inspiration and motivation see this: [How To Train For Mass | Arnold Schwarzenegger's Blueprint Training Program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9zCgPtsups)